# PDOException during Drupal 8 project migration

Tags: php, pdo, drupal, drupal-8

I have a Drupal 8 project developed on my local. I am trying to move it to Client server which is Windows server 2008 R2 version. Steps I followed:

1. Restored database on DB server (MS SQL)
2. Moved all the project files into client web server
3. Installed PHP 7.3 and it's dependancies (wincache, PHP manager etc)
4. Dropped PDO_sqlsrv drivers into appropriate folders and edited PHP.ini with those locations
5. Changed DB configs in settings.php

When I start the site in IIS  I see the Drupal "website encountered error" message. On the log file I see the below errors:

```
PDOException:  in D:\myproject\web\core\lib\Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer.php on line 79 #0 D:\myproject\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Database\Database.php(371): Drupal\Driver\Database\sqlsrv\Connection::open(Array)
#1 D:\myproject\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Database\Database.php(166): Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection('default', 'default')
#2 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('default')
#3 D:\myproject\web\core\lib\Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer.php(79): call_user_func_array('Drupal\\Core\\Dat...', Array)
#4 D:\myproject\web\core\lib\Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php(173): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService(Array, 'database')
#5 D:\myproject\web\core\lib\Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer.php(260): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('database', 1)
#6 D:\myproject\web\core\lib\Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer.php(62): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array)
#7 D:\myproject\web\core\lib\Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php(173): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService(Array, 'cache.container')
#8 D:\myproject\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel.php(543): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('cache.container')
#9 D:\myproject\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel.php(904): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->getCachedContainerDefinition()
#10 D:\myproject\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel.php(476): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer()
#11 D:\myproject\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel.php(692): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot()
#12 D:\myproject\web\index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#13 {main}
```

Not sure how to fix this. Any help?!

Comment: It seems like an error regarding your settings file i believe.
Probably wrong host value or port. Is host like
'host' => 'localhost'?

Comment: My database is in a different server from host server. So the host has that server name and not 'localhost'